# differentiability of characteristic function - additional question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

In Wikipedia, we have the theorem about characteristic functions:

Provided the n'th moment exist, the characteristic function can be differentiated n times and:

$$ E[X^n] = i^{-n} \phi_X^{(n)}(0) = i^{-n} \left[ \frac{d^n}{dt^n} \phi_X(t) \right]_{t=0}.$$

My additonal question is:

Is it possible to conclude the opposite, with some restrictions about $X$?
If $X$ is a non-negative random variable, can we conclude:

$\phi_X$ is differentiabel in $0$ $\Rightarrow$ The first moment exist?

---

I have a result which states:
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables on $(\Omega, F, P)$, and assume $E[X_1^-]<\infty$ and $E[X_1^+]=\infty$. Then for every $M \in (0, \infty)$ we have, that:

$$\text{min}\{X_1,M\}\in \mathcal{L}^1(P) \text{ and } \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{min}\{X_k,M\} \geq E[\text{min}\{X_1,M\}]$$

I tried to use this, but haven't gotten far.

Comment: You really tried to use the paragraph below the line to prove the assertion above it?

Comment: Yeah, I really tried. Why?

Comment: Because they seem totally unrelated.

Comment: Okay. That was a hint to this exercise. That is why I was trying to use it.

Comment: gariba, where did you get this? [It seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#cite_ref-11) the answer is 'no'. A counterexample would be 'distributions with finite mean whose characteristic functions are not twice differentiable (such as the so-called stable distributions with index between 1 and 2)' (From Allan Gut's An Intermediate Course in Probability). Also $c\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{cos(nt)}{n^2 \ln (n)}$ where $c$ is the normalising constant from Selected Topics in Characteristic Functions by Nikolai G. Ushakov, who also  cites Lukacs (1970)

Comment: gariba, Wiki says $X$ is stable if for any $aX_1+bX_2$ with positive $a,b$, there exists $cX+d$ with positive $c$ and the same distribution if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent copies of $X$. Seems to relate to the hint, but you don't specify independence. If you did, is it related?

Comment: Dumb question: the point is to show that $\phi_X'(0)$ exists?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, that is the point.

Comment: @BCLC are you sure about the $c\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos(nt)}{n^2\ln(n)}$ example? That’s the characteristic function of a *symmetric* random variable. But the question is about *nonnegative* random variables, and this I’m having trouble concluding. (I’ve asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478791/nonnegative-random-variable-whose-characteristic-function-is-differentiable-at-0 )

Answer (score 2):

Here are the details of a counter-example from Chung's book: let $X$ take integer values with $P\{X=n\}=\frac C {n^{2} \ln {|n|}}$ for $|n| >1$, $0$ for $n=0,1,-1$ where $C$ is chosen such that the probabilities add up to 1. The characteristic function is given by $\phi (t) =2C\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\cos (nt)} {n^{2} \ln n}$ Let $S_k$ be the k-th partial sum. Then $S_k'=-2C\sum_{n=2}^{k} \frac {\sin (nt)} {n \ln n}$. It is well known that if $\{a_n\}$ decreases to $0$  then $\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ converges uniformly iff $na_n \to 0$ $\cdots$(1). In our case this condition is satisfied. Hence $S_k \to \phi$ uniformly and $S_k' \to g$ uniformly for some function $g$. An elementary calculus argument shows that $\phi$ id differentiable with derivative $g$. [ Write $S_k(x)-S_k (0)=\int_0^{x} S_k'(y)dy$ and take limits to get $\phi (x)-\phi (0) =\int _0 ^{x} g(y)dy$. Being a uniform limit of continuous functions $g$ is continuous so we get $\phi '(x)=g(x)$]. Thus $\phi'(0)$ exist. But $E|X|=\infty$ because $\sum_2^{\infty} \frac 1 {n \ln n} =\infty$ A reference for (1) is p. 112 of Fourier series by R E Edwards
It is easy to modify this example to get a non-negative random variable with the same properties. In fact $X$ is symmetrization of a random variable $Y$ taking only the values $2,3,...$ and the characteristic function of $Y$ has the same properties.

Comment: Are you sure it’s so straightforward to show all this for the characteristic function for $Y$ taking the values $2, 3, …$? It doesn’t have exactly the same properties because it has a nontrivial imaginary part involving $\sin(nt)$, and I’m having trouble finding a reference for the corresponding statement for the convergence of $\sum a_n \cos(nx)$. So it’s not so clear to me that the partial sums converge. (Also when you take limits to get $\int_0^x g(y) dy$, how are you passing the limit into the integral?)

Answer (score 2):

The example from Chung's book cannot be modified to work for a non-negative random variable. By [1], Section XVII.2a (page 565), for any random variable $X$ with transform $\phi(t)=E[e^{itX}]$, the existence of the derivative $\phi'(0)$ implies that the limit
$$\lim_{r \to \infty}  E[X \cdot{\bf 1}_{|X| \le r}]$$
exists and is finite. Of course if $X \ge 0$ a.s., then this limit equals
$E[X]$ by monotone convergence.

[1] Feller, William. An introduction to probability theory and its applications, vol 2. John Wiley & Sons, 1971 (republished 2008.)