# Nonnegative random variable whose characteristic function is differentiable at 0 has first moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I’m trying to prove the following claim:

> Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable, and let $\phi(t) = \mathbb E\left[e^{itX}\right]$ be its characteristic function. Suppose $\phi$ is differentiable at $t=0$. Then $\mathbb E[X] < \infty$.

This is a component of an exercise in my probability theory textbook (Achim Klenke, “Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course”, Exercise 15.4.4(iii)).

This question has also been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720021/differentiability-of-characteristic-function-additional-question), and there’s an answer that supposedly gives a counterexample, but I’m not convinced: the counterexample is a symmetric random variable instead of nonnegative, and it’s not clear to me how the characteristic function of a a symmetric random variable relates to the corresponding nonnegative random variable (i.e. its absolute value).

**What I’ve tried:** Klenke has a proof of the existence of $2n^\textrm{th}$ moments when $\phi^{(2n)}(0)$ exists for some $n \geq 1$, but I’ve been having trouble adapting the proof to the first derivative case. I tried considering a symmetric random variable $Y$ for which $Y^2 = X$ (and thus $\mathbb E[Y^2] = \mathbb E[X]$). If I were able to prove $\phi_Y’’(0)$ exists, then I’d be done. But letting $f(x) = x^2$, and noting that $f_* \mathbb P_Y = \mathbb P_X$, I ended up computing:
$$
\phi_Y(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{ity} \mathbb P_Y[dy] = \mathbb P[Y=0] + 2\int_{(0,\infty)} \cos\left(t\sqrt x\right) \mathbb P_X[dx]
$$
and it’s not at all obvious to me that this map should be differentiable (let alone twice differentiable).

Any suggestions/places to find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is correct. By [1] Section XVII.2a (page 565), for any random variable $X$ with transform $\phi(t)=E[e^{itX}]$, the existence of the derivative $\phi'(0)$ implies that the limit
$$\lim_{r \to \infty}  E[X \cdot{\bf 1}_{|X| \le r}]$$
exists and is finite. Of course if $X \ge 0$ a,s, then this limit equals
$E[X]$ by monotone convergence.

[1] Feller, William. An introduction to probability theory and its applications, vol 2. John Wiley & Sons, 1971 (republished 2008.)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick. The strange thing is Feller’s strategy in proving that the limit exists and is finite seems to be grounded in infinitely divisible distributions, which come in the chapter *following* the one from which this exercise comes. I wonder if there’s an easier way to show $\displaystyle \lim_{r \to \infty} \mathbb E[X \cdot \mathbb 1_{\{|X| \leq r\}}] < \infty$ whenever $\phi’_X(0)$ exists…