# Given that derivative of ch.f. exists is $E[|X|]<\infty$

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Suppose the derivative of a characteristic function for the random variable $X$ at 0 is $ia$. Do we know that $X$ is in $L^1$. I know the converse is true, but how does one prove the forward direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nonnegative random variable whose characteristic function is differentiable at 0 has first moment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478791/nonnegative-random-variable-whose-characteristic-function-is-differentiable-at-0)

Comment: Chapter 3 of Durrett PTE 5e would interest you.